# Reference Request: Mean Value Property over a ball in $R^n$ in Standard Coordinates

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a good reference on dealing with the Laplace equation rigorously. In particular I am looking for:

- Proof of The Mean Value Property in $R^n$ using Green's Second Identity.
- Proof of The Maximum Property
- Derivation of the Poisson Formula

Any book/notes/pdfs/webpaces/etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Evans PDE book covers all of this rigorously.

Comment: I second that. This is an excellent reference for a self-contained easy-to-read but rigorous treatment of the basics about PDEs in general.